# Android device screen lock blocks JNI method call

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-ndk

In my app I have used Android NDK and JNI methods. I am invoking my JNI methods from JAVA using separate AsyncTask which is a time taking task might take around 50Secs. So while task is running mode in the mean time if device sleeps or auto-locked that AsyncTask in my Activity stops executing and my current activity is finished.

please someone guide should I do in this kind problem. Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Don't use `AsyncTask`. It is designed for operations that take "a few seconds at the most" (see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)). For long-running operations, they recommend `Executor`, `ThreadPoolExecutor`, and `FutureTask` instead.

2) Obtain a [partial wake lock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html).

Comment: I have already tried this but no success. Any other example or code if you are aware of

Comment: The problem is probably the amount of time it actually takes to complete the task. `AsyncTask` is not designed for long-running operations (the documentation says "a few seconds at the most"). You may need to start a `Thread` in a more conventional manner... and obtain a partial wake lock.

Answer (score 0):

Use this before starting the long task to prevent the screen lock during the task execution.
Add permission in androidmanifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
```

before starting the task

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
lock.disableKeyguard();
```